# What is v-if in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx

What is v-if in react? I tried this but My div with loading class does not work when the loading data changes, so the div doesn't re-render itself.
codes is here:

```
{
    loading &&
    <div className="loading"></div>
}
```

**I'm changing loading with a function, this function working with onclick event.**

all of my code:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
export class LoginPage extends React.Component{
    render(){
        let username = '',
            password = '',
            loading = false

        function login(){
            loading = true;
            console.log(loading)
        }

        return (
            <div className="App">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css"
                      integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA=="
                      crossOrigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
                        {
                            loading &&
                            <div className="loading"></div>
                        }
                <div className="login">
                    <h1>Login/Register</h1>
                    <div>
                        <i className="fas fa-user"></i>
                        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => username = e.target.value} placeholder="Username" maxLength="15"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <i className="fas fa-lock"></i>
                        <input type="Password" placeholder="Password" onChange={(e) => password = e.target.value} maxLength="18"/>
                    </div>
                    <button onClick={() => login()}>Login/Register</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you changing the `loading` variable?

Comment: With a function, function working with onclick event.

Comment: use `loading` as a state variable, and change with the useState hook, so that it triggers a rerender, or with setState if you're on a class component

Comment: like this: `const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)`. And then, when you want to set a new value to it, do `setLoading(false)`

Comment: If you're on a functional component, the example above will work

Comment: i don't get it :(

Comment: Declare your variable like this: `const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)`
And use `setLoading(false)` when you wish to change its value to false

Comment: can u write jsx example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you read about React State, some things in this piece of code are wrong. But let's fix your problem.

First add this variable to the state and then change it with `setState`, to trigger a rerender:

```
export class LoginPage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        loading: false
      };
    }

    login(){
      this.setState({ loading: true })
      console.log(this.state.loading)
    }

    render(){
      let username = '',
          password = '',

      // your return will stay the same
    }
}
```

Comment: I getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')

Comment: declare your `login` function outside of render method, I'll edit my answer

Comment: thank you dude, i wasn't know state yesterday sorry about thay. :)

Comment: @yefee no worries, I'd recommend you read a lot about, it is the most important thing to understand about React in my opinion. Also, if you just began learning react, I'd suggest you learn functional components, rather than class components, which is what you're using in this example